# client side kg to lb not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

What I'm trying to do is if the user types in 100 and selects lbs it'll store as 100 in the database but if the user selected kgs it should save as 45. Currently it saves as whatever I type in no matter what if I select kg or lb

```
{!! Form::label('weightLb', 'Weight:', array('class' => 'col-md-4 control-label')) !!}
{!! Form::text('weightLb', $user->weightLb, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
{!! Form::select('weight_unit', array('lbs' => 'lbs', 'kgs' => 'kgs')) !!}

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#weight_unit').change(function () {
    var v = $('weightLb').val();
    if ($('#weight_unit').val() != 'lbs') {
        $('weightLb').val(v / 0.4535923);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: `$('weightLb').val();` doesn't do anything.  You could just check to see if `$('#weight_unit').val() !== 'lbs'` and adjust the value accordingly.  Are you looking for help saving to the database?

Comment: Okay I have updated my OP. Currently it stores whatever I type into the weightLb textbox to the database no matter if I select kg or lbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate units on the fly, than this would be correct way:

```js
var weightAmount = $('#weight_amount');
var weightUnit = $('#weight_unit');

function unitChange() {
    var currentUnit = weightUnit.val();
    var toReturn = $.trim(weightAmount.val());
    if (toReturn) {
        toReturn *= currentUnit == 'lbs' ? 2.204623 : .4535923;
        weightAmount.val(toReturn.toFixed(7) * 1);
    };
};
weightUnit.on('change', unitChange);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <input id="weight_amount" />
    <select id="weight_unit">
        <option value="lbs">lbs</option>
        <option value="kgs">kgs</option>
    </select>
</p>
```

Also on [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qno2qkyw/2/).

What I have to advice is: always store the weight as **one** of `kg`, `g` or `lbs` in database. Otherwise, you will have problems with conversions, comparing, selections etc.

Comment: I copied and pasted your code exactly and it will not work for me. So odd.

Comment: Look at the input and select IDs I used: `weight_amount` and `weight_unit`. You used `weightLb`, which is not appropriate for the field (can also be kilograms). So, you need to change either script or html.

Comment: Yes I know at first I changed the text input to `weightLb` and it didn't work. So I copied and pasted your code exactly as it is, with the input and select, and it still didn't work

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser console? If you use old jQuery, than bind this way: `weightUnit.change(unitChange);`